# video continu asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, television

I would like to create an asp.net website that display video in continu like TV.
i am not sure which technology to use. 
The app will give a feel like a tv to the users.
any suggestion or link you can share?

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at the following link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/csharpwebvideo04212007133218pm/csharpwebvideo.aspx

It explains how to display video in a web site.

Comment: Well i have come up with one on my own and will be releasing new version soon Check it out on http://www.filsdufaso.com/videos.aspx